# Background images responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I've got a problem where my image is not responsive when I resize my window. I've tried fixing it by placing the image between the html tags and using the image with CSS 100% width, but it doesn't work well.

After that I tried `background-size: cover;` and `background-size: contain;`. If do this it's responsive but the height is way too small. I want the image to display full height, not 400px or something. When I put in `height: 100vh;` or `height: 100%;` it's not responsive.

```css
nav {
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
}
nav#menu{
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    }

.js nav#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    }

nav#menu.active {
    max-height: 25em;
    }

nav#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

nav#menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
nav#menu li a:hover{
  color:#668bc3;
    }

#intro {
    background-image: url(../images/hero2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100vh;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    }
```

```html
 <header id="intro">
  <a href="#menu" class="menu-link">
     <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <nav id="menu">
    <div class="navsvg"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></div>
    <ul>  
      <li><a href="#intro">Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href="#howitworks">How it works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
      <li><a href="#prototype">Prototype</a></li>
      <li><a href="#posts">Posts</a></li>    
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>        
    </ul>
  </nav>
    
</header>
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm not clear on your goal here. Do you just want the image to fill the background of the header element? Regardless of the height of the header?

Comment: Yes, aslong as the image is fully visible. Right now it always keeps cutting off my height of the image itself. When i put the header on 100% height or in px its not responsive anymore when u resize.

Comment: Well, if your image doesn't have the same aspect ratio as your header, you're going to have to accept one of the following: **1)** cropping along x or y-axis, **2)** _"letterboxing"_ when the image's aspect ratio cannot fill the space or **3)** stretching. Which would you prefer?

Comment: first one seems to the best option i guess.

Answer (score 0):

`contain` will leave blank spaces, `cover` will cut something out, and `100% 100%` will stretch. You can't satisfy everything with pictures out of proportion. (It doesn't even make sense that it would be possible).

The best way to solve this would be using media queries to change into a different proportion image for different screen sizes.

### Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #intro {
        background-image: url(../images/hero-mobile.jpg); /* Example Image */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite tough to have a *responsive* image always fill up an element without cropping or stretching. *Especially* when there's content restrictions/requirements, i.e. element has to be at least this tall or wide because of the content.

As a result I think [**`background-size: cover;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) might be your best option. It **will** crop your image though it will make sure that it fills the element.

To reduce some of the cropping try to provide an image that has a similar aspect ration as the element that it will be applied to, i.e. don't use a square or portrait oriented image for an element that is 10 times as wide as it is tall - a lot will be cropped as you can see below.

You can use media queries to deliver a version of the image with a more optimized aspect ratio and even art direct it a bit (focus on a certain area of the image).

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.x-axis,
.y-axis,
.sorta-optimized {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed rebeccapurple;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.x-axis {
  background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/600/300/?image=100' );
}
.y-axis {
  background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/300/600/?image=100' );
}
.sorta-optimized {
  background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/400/100/?image=100' );
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .sorta-optimized {
    background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/600/100/?image=100' );
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .sorta-optimized {
    background-image: url( 'https://unsplash.it/800/100/?image=100' );
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="x-axis">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="y-axis">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sorta-optimized">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Below are some reference images for what I used in the Snippet above.

**`.x-axis` image**

[image]

**`.y-axis` image**

[image]

**`.sort-optimized` image** - pseudo art directed and attempting to *"match"* aspect ratio with element size.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try giving the image styling like so, see if this works:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 769px) { #intro { height: 100%; max-width: ?px; }}
```

Adding the @media specification will ensure that the styling will effect devices with screen widths of 769px and under. You'll want to specify what width you'll prefer in place of the question mark.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Percentage heights require that the parent have a height specified. None is defined here, hence `height: 100%;` won't work.